# Bluemix DevOps Serviceのエディターの保存について

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluemix

IBM Bluemix DevOps ServicesでJavaScriptのコードを書いています。
エディターで明示的にファイルの保存をしなくても変更したコードは保存されているようですが、変更はどの時点で保存されるのでしょうか？デプロイのタイミングでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDS(IBM Bluemix DevOps Services)のエディターは自動保存の設定になっています。デフォルトでは変更直後(正確には0.25ミリ秒ごと)に自動保存されます。
もし自動保存が必要ないのであれば、設定を解除することも可能です。EDIT CODEが選択されている状態で、画面上部のメニューにあるスパナの形のアイコン「ローカル・エディター設定」にて、設定を変更できます。